# Cognito Integration with LDAP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am starting a new project and this one needs first an integration between Cognito and LDAP, this is my first time and I've been doing some research about it but is not clear to me yet.

Any knowledge transfer you may give me is really appreciated.

Thank you very much.